# SAML ADFS 2.0 InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message

Tags: spring-boot, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I'm trying to implement an authentication/authorization mechanism using Spring Boot 2.1.6 + SAML 2.0 (1.0.10.RELEASE) + ADFS 2.0 in one of our projects.
Requests from SP to IdP (ADFS 2.0) and responses from IdP to SP go well. The InResponseTo value corresponds to the AuthnRequest's id sent to the IdP.
However, for any reason WebSSOProfileConsumer, while processing the IdP response doesn't find the message into HttpSessionStore - 
`org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorage#retrieveMessage.`
Actually, the map is empty.

```
15:11:20.603 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.s.s.HttpSessionStorage Storing message a2cj8718fe73aa014a9fadi5e8eagcj to session 1DDE042B05BC7239053734119975A884
15:11:21.948 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-8] o.s.s.s.l.SAMLDefaultLogger AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;ENTITY_ID;http://ADFS_HOST_NAME/adfs/services/trust;;;
15:12:03.882 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.s.SAMLProcessingFilter Request is to process authentication
15:12:03.882 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.s.SAMLProcessingFilter Attempting SAML2 authentication using profile urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser
15:12:04.026 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.s.p.SAMLProcessorImpl Retrieving message using binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
15:12:04.055 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.s.u.SAMLUtil Found endpoint org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.impl.AssertionConsumerServiceImpl@5ef389cc for request URL https://SP_HOST_NAME:8443/saml/SSO based on location attribute in metadata
15:12:13.127 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.s.s.HttpSessionStorage Message a2cj8718fe73aa014a9fadi5e8eagcj not found in session 8E4443CA6E75F206154DA5D80F3E8C42
15:12:37.889 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] o.s.s.s.SAMLAuthenticationProvider Error validating SAML message
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a2cj8718fe73aa014a9fadi5e8eagcj
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:175)
```

I see that request session id is different than response session id.

The ADFS reponse has this format

```
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
    Destination="https://SP_HOST_NAME:8443/saml/SSO" ID="_9bb358cc-841d-432a-b2a6-87470a535d72"
    InResponseTo="a59545jh68b8fa7d3a1cc615j4gd9" IssueInstant="2020-04-03T10:38:08.922Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://ADFS_HOST_NAME/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
            xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/></e:EncryptionMethod>
                    <KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=XXX YYYY, OU=Users, O=ORGANISATION_NAME, L=LOCATION, S=Unknown, C=COUNTRY</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>1160660393</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <e:CipherData>
                        <e:CipherValue>A_VALUE</e:CipherValue>
                    </e:CipherData>
                </e:EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>A_SECOND_VALUE</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. :)
Thanks.